# How to run script on Amazon EC2 without keeping an ssh pipe open?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a script built to log historical data into an Amazon Redshift instance. The script will likely need to run for a very long time, perhaps over 24 hours before it can run to completion.

I have tried ssh-ing into my EC2 instance and running the script from there, however the after a few hours I leave my laptop or shut the lid and the pipe is broken, stopping the script before it runs to completion.

How can I get a script running on my EC2, and then never have to worry about it stopping execution prematurely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
nohup yourshellcommandhere  &
```

Will run in the background and not require you to have an interactive ssh session active.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the & sign for?

Comment: @johncorser - the & backgrounds the command.  Another way you could do this if you want to be able to go back and see the console output is to run it in a [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session. The screen package is available in virtually any linux distro.

Answer (score 3):

Like @johncorser mentioned, use [Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html):

You can log out and re-attach the screen later on.
`yum install screen` or `apt-get install screen`

Then just type `screen`.
It'll give you a "virtual" shell, which you can "detatch".

Try:
`screen
sleep 999
CTRL-a then d`

You can log out and back in again, and do `screen -r` to re-attach the virtual terminal.

Most of screen's hotkeys start with `CTRL-a` (lowercase a), then some letter.
If you're just going to learn one, learn `CTRL-a, ?` which displays help screen and list the other keys.

Another incredibly useful hotkeys:

`CTRL-a, c`: creates another virtual terminals

`CTRL-a, n`: cycles through all your virtual terminals

Just remember `CTRL-a, ?` and then try them all :)